# Project attribute values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Not sure if this is possible. I have a subset of 'MarketInventory' nodes:

```
<MARKET_INVENTORY _Type="TotalSales" _MonthRangeType="Prior7To12Months" _Count="18"/>
<MARKET_INVENTORY _Type="TotalSales" _MonthRangeType="Prior4To6Months" _Count="6"/>
<MARKET_INVENTORY _Type="TotalSales" _MonthRangeType="Last3Months" _Count="11"/>
<MARKET_INVENTORY _Type="TotalSales" _TrendType="Stable"/>
```

filtered on the _Type="TotalSales" node.

I'm wondering if it's possible to project the _Count value attributes into this class:

```
public class MarketInventoryListing
{
    public string Prior7To12Months { get; set; }
    public string Prior4To6Months { get; set; }
    public string LastThreeMonths { get; set; }
}
```

This is as far as I got:

```
var marketInventoryTotalListings = from totalListings in xe.Descendants("MARKET_INVENTORY")
where (string) totalListings.Attribute("_Type") == "TotalSales"
select new MarketInventoryListing()
{
    Prior7To12Months = 
    (
        from thing in totalListings.Descendants()
        where (string)totalListings.Attribute("_MonthRangeType") == "Prior7To12Months"
        select thing.Attribute("_Count").Value
    )
};
```

Comment: ``Prior7To12Months`` is of type ``string`` while linq query is returning ``IEnumerable<string>``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working for 2 reasons:

1. Select is returning IEnumerable where as you need a single string
2. All MARKET_INVENTORY elements are on the same level so "from thing in totalListings.Descendants()" is not returning anything. All these elements are siblings at this point.

I changed your code to address those issues and it works as below:

```
var marketInventoryTotalListings = (from totalListings in xe.Descendants("MARKET_INVENTORY")
                                   where (string)totalListings.Attribute("_Type") == "TotalSales"
                                   select new MarketInventoryListing()
                                   {
                                      Prior7To12Months =
                                      (
                                           from thing in totalListings.Parent.Descendants()
                                           where (string)totalListings.Attribute("_MonthRangeType") == "Prior7To12Months"
                                           select thing.Attribute("_Count").Value
                                      ).FirstOrDefault(),
                                   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there will be just one node for each, then you can use `FirstOrDefault` like this:-

```
var marketInventoryTotalListings = from totalListings in xe.Descendants("MARKET_INVENTORY")
  where (string)totalListings.Attribute("_Type") == "TotalSales"
  let prior712 = xe.Descendants("MARKET_INVENTORY")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("_MonthRangeType") == "Prior7To12Months")
  let prior46 = xe.Descendants("MARKET_INVENTORY")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("_MonthRangeType") == "Prior4To6Months")
  let last3 = xe.Descendants("MARKET_INVENTORY")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("_MonthRangeType") == "Last3Months")
  select new MarketInventoryListing
     {
         Prior7To12Months = prior712 != null ? (string)prior712.Attribute("_Count") : "",
         Prior4To6Months = prior712 != null ? (string)prior46.Attribute("_Count") : "",
         LastThreeMonths = last3 != null ? (string)last3.Attribute("_Count") : "",
     };
```

Otherwise if they are multiple then you should have `IEnumerable<string>` as the datatype in the properties of MarketInventoryListing instead of `string`.

Comment: Rahul - I changed 'xdoc' to 'xe' in the 'let' statements and added 'FirstOrDefault() to the end and it worked. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @FoolongCv- Yup that was a typo ;) Corrected.